# Группировка по двум столбцам с помощью linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

У меня есть массив(текстовый файл) из 1000 строк, разбитый запятыми, вот пример строк :

```
**#,LM,Jam ID,Date Occurred,Time Jammed,Rc,Rt,Cl,Jam Text**
001,03,043,04/07/15 16:02,00:00:25,00,00,00,Indexer #1 shot pin state is unknown
002,02,030,09/24/15 16:39,00:00:04,00,00,01,ATT unable to detect tray at Gripper
003,01,044,09/24/15 16:38,00:00:25,00,00,01,Main tray is hanging on guides or stuck in gripper.
004,01,044,09/24/15 16:36,00:01:51,00,01,00,Main tray is hanging on guides or stuck in gripper.
005,02,030,09/24/15 15:11,00:00:04,00,00,01,ATT unable to detect tray at Gripper
006,01,044,09/24/15 15:10,00:00:27,00,01,00,Main tray is hanging on guides or stuck in gripper.
007,01,044,09/24/15 15:10,00:00:21,00,01,00,Main tray is hanging on guides or stuck in gripper.
008,02,030,09/21/15 15:17,00:00:19,00,00,01,ATT unable to detect tray at Gripper
009,01,045,09/21/15 15:15,00:01:32,00,01,00,Aux tray is hanging on guides or stuck in gripper.
010,01,045,09/21/15 15:15,00:00:17,00,01,00,Aux tray is hanging on guides or stuck in gripper.
011,04,030,09/18/15 19:28,00:00:55,01,02,00,Missing sort device(s) on sort boat. B1
012,05,029,09/18/15 19:24,00:01:39,06,06,01,TS Picker missing parts:Ck #1 A1
013,05,016,09/18/15 19:21,00:01:12,00,01,00,Picker detects parts stuck in nests:Ck #1 A1
014,05,016,09/18/15 19:20,00:00:23,00,01,00,Picker detects parts stuck in nests:Ck #1 A1
015,05,016,09/18/15 19:17,00:01:07,02,03,00,Picker detects parts stuck in nests:Ck #1 A1
016,05,016,09/18/15 19:15,00:00:17,00,01,00,Picker detects parts stuck in nests:Ck #1 A1
017,05,029,09/18/15 01:52,00:00:18,00,01,00,TS Picker missing parts:Ck #1 A1
018,05,029,09/17/15 17:09,00:00:05,00,01,00,TS Picker missing parts:Ck #1 A1
019,05,029,09/17/15 17:05,00:00:06,00,01,00,TS Picker missing parts:Ck #1 A1
020,05,029,09/17/15 16:35,00:00:07,00,01,00,TS Picker missing parts:Ck #1 A1
021,05,029,09/17/15 15:37,00:00:08,00,01,00,TS Picker missing parts:Ck #1 A1
022,02,030,09/17/15 15:22,00:00:56,01,01,01,ATT unable to detect tray at Gripper
023,05,029,09/17/15 12:17,02:29:47,01,02,00,TS Picker missing parts:Ck #1 A1
024,02,016,09/17/15 12:25,00:02:15,02,03,00,ATT unable to open the Gripper
025,05,029,09/17/15 12:11,00:00:24,00,01,00,TS Picker missing parts:Ck #1 A1
026,05,029,09/17/15 09:50,00:00:06,00,01,00,TS Picker missing parts:Ck #1 A1
027,05,029,09/17/15 09:49,00:00:10,00,01,00,TS Picker missing parts:Ck #1 A1
028,05,015,09/17/15 09:48,00:00:04,00,01,00,Picker can't detect all parts:Ck #1 A1
029,05,015,09/17/15 09:47,00:00:05,00,01,00,Picker can't detect all parts:Ck #1 A1
```

Я написал LINQ запрос к нему, который считает общее время,которое складывается из поля(Time Jammed) для ошибок(позиция Jam ID), но загвоздка в том , что для узлов всего их 6 (позиция LM), встречаются одинаковые по номеру ошибки. Как сгруппировать так чтобы он выдавал информацию номер узла номер ошибки общее время на ошибку ????
Вот мой LINQ запрос

```
var error = (from line in readText
    let a = line.Split(',')
    where a.Length >= 5 && Regex.IsMatch(a[4], @"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}")
    let Num = a[2]
    let timeAttr = a[4].Split(':')
    let timeUsage = TimeSpan.FromHours(int.Parse(timeAttr[0])) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(timeAttr[1])) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse(timeAttr[2]))
        where timeUsage <= TimeSpan.FromHours(2)
    select new { Num, timeUsage } into Uzel
    group Uzel by Uzel.Num into g
    select new
    {
        Num = g.Key,
        TotalTime = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(arg => arg.timeUsage.Ticks)),
        AverageTime = new TimeSpan((long)g.Average(arg => arg.timeUsage.Ticks))
    });
```

Надо чтобы данные выводились в таком виде (в общем какие встречаются на узле и время для них только на данном узле и так для 2 3 и т. д. узла)

```
На узле 01 ошибка 001 время 00:0:00
           ошибка 002 время 00:02:00
           ошибка 003 время 00:40:00
           ...................
На узле 02 ошибка 021 время 00:03:00
           ошибка 003 время 00:40:00
```

Comment: Ну хоть один нормальный вопрос на эту тему...

Comment: а если делать две группировки, первая по номеру узла, вторая по номеру ошибки?

Comment: @Creater не проще было бы один раз нормально зарегистрироваться и задать все свои вопросы чем плодить кучу однотипных вопросов с разных аккаунтов?

Comment: и напишу здесь, если Вы все таки удалите свой вопрос оформленный ответом, вот [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/457078/179270) Вам показали как сделать, это должно удовлетворить Ваши нужды, Вам потребуется только немного переписать под себя

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

В таких случаях можно сгруппировать по анонимному типу, вот так:

```
.GroupBy(e => new {e.NodeNumber, e.ErrorNumber})
```

Вы напрасно смешали в одном запросе чтение данных из файла и их группировку. Чтение данных из внешнего источника это одна задача, формирование отчета по данным - вторая. Разные задачи лучше решать отдельно, тогда код будет гораздо проще читать и поддерживать.

Поэтому я бы посоветовал вам сделать примерно так:

```
// сначала читаем данные:
List<Error> errors = ParseErrorsFromFile(); // функция просто парсит необходимые данные из файла

// теперь группируем:
var groupedErrors = errors
    .GroupBy(e => new {e.NodeNumber, e.ErrorNumber}) // вот то что вам нужно
    .Select(gr => new
            {
                gr.Key.NodeNumber,
                gr.Key.ErrorNumber,
                TotalTime = gr.Sum(x => x.TimeJummed)
            })
    .ToList();
```

Класс Error может выглядеть вот так:

```
public class Error
{
    public int NodeNumber { get; set; }

    public int ErrorNumber { get; set; }

    public int TimeJummed { get; set; }
}
```

[Здесь](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ekrYdS) работающий пример.

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто сделать такой `group by`:

```
group Uzel by new { Uzel.Num, Uzel.StatusCode }
```

чтобы получилось так:

```
var error = (from line in readText
let a = line.Split(',')
where a.Length >= 5 && Regex.IsMatch(a[4], @"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}")
let Num = a[2]
let timeAttr = a[4].Split(':')
let StatusCode = a[1]
let timeUsage = TimeSpan.FromHours(int.Parse(timeAttr[0])) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(timeAttr[1])) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse(timeAttr[2]))
where timeUsage <= TimeSpan.FromHours(2)
select new { Num, timeUsage, StatusCode } into Uzel
group Uzel by new { Uzel.Num, Uzel.StatusCode } into g
select new { Num = g.Key.Num, StatusCode = g.Key.StatusCode, TotalTime = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(arg => arg.timeUsage.Ticks)), AverageTime = new TimeSpan((long)g.Average(arg => arg.timeUsage.Ticks)) }
);
```

А вообще я тебе уже давал [ссылку](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xLMoIk) на код, который это делает. И если бы ты не регистрировал кучу аккаунтов, а пользовался одним, то уже давно бы это все увидел.

Comment: Да что ж никто не использует `TimeSpan.Parse`?

Comment: @Qwertiy там, в его предыдущих вопросах была ссылка на весь файл с данными. В них встречаются такие, которые не парсятся из-за того, что там часов > 24. Как-то так в общем.

Comment: @ApInvent ну согласитесь что этот вопрос уже более качественен, еще n* учеток и все будет

Comment: @Bald56rus =) Были уже вопросы тоже достаточно подробные, с примером его кода, с примером данных и т.п.

Comment: @Bald56rus Кстати, запрос который он "сам" написал - это из предыдущих ответов =)

Comment: @Qwertiy  пример того, что не парсилось: 113:37:37

Comment: Идею понял (хотя, а нельзя как-то заставить распарситься?), но конкретно этот пример не подойдёт под `@"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}"`, которая там стоит вместо пропуска первой строки.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, действительно, в этом ошибка. Верное замечание. У `TimeSpan.Parse` есть перегрузка принимающая `IFormatProvider` - может быть как-то через нее. Но тут уже  явно не проще получается =)

Answer (score 0):

http://ideone.com/a1gm2u

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    private static IEnumerable<string> ReadAllLines()
    {
        for (string line; (line=Console.ReadLine()) != null; )
            yield return line;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var res = from line in ReadAllLines().Skip(1) select line.Split(',') into parts
                  group parts by parts[2] into g
                  select new
                  {
                      Name = g.Key,
                      TotalTime = g.Select(x => TimeSpan.Parse(x[4])).Aggregate(new TimeSpan(), (a,b) => a+b)
                  };

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", String.Join("\n", res));
    }
}
```

Comment: а я тс понял что ему необходима группировка по узлам, ошибкам и там уже время

Comment: @Bald56rus, перечитал - возможно.

Comment: @ Bald56rus,правильно понял